# How to enable all SpringBoot actuator endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

`SpringBoot v2.5.1`

I would like to have all actuator endpoints (described in documentation) available.
Following the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.enabling), have added actuator starter dependency and a property, but most of the endpoints are not available (HTTP 404).

The only available endpoint is `GET /actuator/health`, but it shows useless info: `{"status": "UP"}`

Added property `management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true`.

Added dependency:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Result of `GET /actuator`

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:9999/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health-path": {
            "href": "http://localhost:9999/actuator/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "http://localhost:9999/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

**What is the minimal set up to enable actuator endpoints?**

Answer (score 1):

Add `micrometer-core` and `micrometer-registry-prometheus` dependencies in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<!-- Spring boot actuator to expose metrics endpoint -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Micormeter core dependecy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add below properties in your `application.properties` file:

```
#Metrics related configurations
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled          = true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include    = *
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled       = true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled = true
```

If you need to expose everything over HTTP then you need to set `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` as shown in above example. In your code this property is missing. Please refer [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing) if you wish to expose specific endpoints. I have also added dependencies in above examples which are required to expose `prometheus` related endpoints.